# reactor+sse with endless stream which receive from async message in spring boot2

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

Here is the scenario.
a)Tablet use http GET to get some resource and the resource is get from another system via async message. demo code as below

in Controller

```
@GetMapping
public List<User> listUser() {
    return service.listUser();
}
```

in Service

```
public List<User> listUser() {
    requestfromAnotherSystem();
    while(!newDataReady) {};
    newDataReady = false;
    return list;
}

public void onMessage(List<User> list) {
    this.list = list;
    newDataReady = true;
}
```

b)the other system may modify the content from time to time and the modification need to be notify the tablet in time;

At the very beginnings I use RabbitMq to notify tablet new change in Service::OnMessage, then I heard Reactor+SSE. Hence I change the code as

in Controller

```
@GetMapping 
public Flux<List<User>> listUser() {
    return service.listUser();
}
```

in Service

```
public Flux<List<User>> listUser() {
    Flux<List<User>> flux = Flux.generate(
            () -> 0,
            (state, sink) -> {
                while(!newData){};
                sink.next(users);
                newData = false;
                return state + 1;
            });
    return flux;
```

My question is a)whether it's a proper way to handle such scenario, b)is there a better solution for that?